# Dotnet not recognizing controller with Angular frontend

Tags: c#, .net, angular, endpoint

I have created the following PersonController.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using PersonApi.Models;

namespace donau_lead_generator.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]

public class PersonController : ControllerBase

{
    private readonly ILogger<PersonController> _logger;

public PersonController(ILogger<PersonController> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}


[HttpPost("addData")]
public Task<ActionResult<Person>> Post(Person person)
{
    Console.WriteLine("I am here");
    return null;
}
```

And the following service:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Person } from './person';

@Injectable()
export class HomeService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient) {
  }


  /** POST: add a new user to the database */
  addUser(user: Person): Observable<Person> {
    return this.http.post<Person>("person/addData", user);
  }
}
```

Which is called in the component like this:

```
this.homeService.addUser(newUser).subscribe(user => {console.warn(user)
}, error => console.error(error)); //maybe create Person
```

I know that the return value etc. is not correct yet, but the main problem is that the endpoint is not recognized:

[image]

My Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();


app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");;

app.Run();
```

If I add the method to the pre generated (weatherforecast) endpoint everything works.

My folder structure:

[image]

**EDIT**

I changed it to, as requested in an answer:

```
[HttpPost("addData")]
public ActionResult<Person> Post(Person person)
{
    Console.WriteLine("I am here");
    return Ok(person);
}
```

However, it still throws the same 404 not found error.

Comment: Did you try `[HttpPost("person/addData")]`

Comment: yes this does not work neither.
The strange thing is I can add enpoints to the pregenerated controller but not new custom controllers.

Comment: @EduardFrankford Are the angular project is located in the MVC project? both of them has the same localHost address ?

Comment: @ayala yes I did not change the folder structure it is still like the automatically generated structure should be.

Comment: Are you sure the URL is correct? (https://localhost:44416/...)? And have you tried calling it from Postman? Can you also paste the content of Person class (and the Person object you construct in Angular)? If the contract don't match, there won't be any successful mapping so if your person objects are not a match, it won't "find it".

Comment: Wow you ```return null``` at the endpoint. Do this ```return Ok(null)```

Comment: @kha yes I am pretty sure because if I use the controller (weatherforecast) which has been generated when creating the project then I can easily add the post endpoint and it works on the fly. However when I add my own PersonController.cs it does not work. 

I think if the objects dont match an other error will be returned and not 404.

Comment: @Betsq9 the return null is just for testing purposes to concentrate that at least the endpoint is reached.

Comment: Yep, it is reached!!! But you endpoint return ```ActionResult```, but you don't define code which have to return, and you return null, and asp net core automatically return 404 because null

Comment: Return this ```return Ok(null)```

Comment: @Betsq9 ok thank you this is new for me because from my point of view it should return 500 internal server error (which it does when using the same method in weatherforecastcontroller.cs). 

return Ok(null) is not compiling.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally found the problem.
The generated project via the dotnet cli, configures a `proxy.conf.js` where it specifies which urls are redirected to the server and `/weatherforecast` is the only url allowed. Thats why the endpoint added in /weatherforecast worked and in an extra controller file not.

To make it work for other endpoints add person in `proxy.conf.js`:

```
const { env } = require('process');

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
  env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:42175';

const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/weatherforecast",
      "/person"
   ],
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    headers: {
      Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
    }
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

to this: `app.MapControllers();`

And your url will be like: https://localhost:44416/Person/addData

Note: When using the `[Route("[controller]")]` attribute with the "[controller]" parameter, in the URL the controller name begins with an uppercase letter

**Update**

Also try to replace this `builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();`
to this: `builder.Services.AddControllers();` because you don't use controller with views

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this still causes the same 404 Not found error. 
My controller is called: PersonController.cs and  app.MapControllerRoute is how dotnet automatically generates the program to use the controller.

Comment: Also you can add Swagger to the project. Via swagger you can call your endpoint

Comment: I see a "Client App" folder in your infrastructure, in my opinion this is a very bad practice. You should split the backend and frontend into two separate projects

Comment: I will try to add Swagger to see which endpoints are available, thanks for the help.
Regarding the ClientApp folder I thought the same, but this is just the way how dotnet automatically generates the structure when creating a dotnet project with angular via the cli :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `ActionResult` types represent various HTTP status codes.

You have an `Task<ActionResult<Person>>` endpoint return type, but you are trying to return `null` with no defined code status, so it needs to be wrapped with Ok() or NotFound() methods, etc.

```
[HttpPost("addData")]
public ActionResult<Person> Post(Person person)
{
    Console.WriteLine("I am here");
    return OK(person);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the new information, however it still throws the 404 error. And if I used the old code in the WeatherforecastController.cs it hit the endpoint but threw a 500 error.